# How come methods can be added as parameters in Java

Tags: java, android, methods, parameters

I had always been ignoring this in Java programming but now I really want to know why.
Here a sample method:

```
public void time()
    {
        final Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            int i =  t;
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(i--);
                if (i< 0)
                {
                    startActivity(intent);
                    timer.cancel();
                }
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
    }
```

I don't understand how is that possible, thanks.

Comment: What, specifically, do you find problematic there?

Comment: What you have dont understand???

Comment: Search for `Anonymous Inner Class` and you will find more about it which is confusing you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to `new TimerTask()`, it is not a method. The word `new` there means a new instance of the class `TimerTask` is being created using its constructor. Thus **the parameter is the instance of TimerTask Class created using its constructor. It is not a method.**

The entire thing below is just creating an instance of TimerTask:

```
new TimerTask() {
            int i =  t;
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(i--);
                if (i< 0)
                {
                    startActivity(intent);
                    timer.cancel();
                }
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
```

You could very well initialize a variable with and then pass that variable as parameter. It would mean the same.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. Thanks to the others too. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are no methods being used as parameters in the example you've given.  However, there is an anonymous class (`TimerTask`) being instantiated with a custom implementation.

Answer (score 0):

`new TimerTask()` is not a method but you are creating a `anonymous inner class` which ends with a `semicolon`. So basically you are not passing a method as parameter but a instance of `TimerTask` class. This [link](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-anonymous-class-example/) explains it well.